# Doctrine DQL, fetching an entire entity with all references and fields correctly

Tags: php, apache, doctrine-orm, php-7.1

How can you fetch an object with DQL and get all the fields and references correctly?
When I use the following statement to fetch a list of entities:

```
return $this->orm->createQuery('SELECT pp FROM PagePlugin pp where pp.page = :page')->setParameter('page', $page)->getResult();
```

I will get a list of PagePlugins where each `PagePlugin` has one reference to a `Plugin`:

```
/**
 * @var \Plugin
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Plugin", inversedBy="pagePlugin", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="plugin_id", referencedColumnName="plugin_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * })
 */
private $plugin;
```

When iterating over the result, the `Plugin` entity that is linked to the PagePlugins do not have a name:

```
$pagePlugin->getPlugin()
DoctrineProxies\__CG__\Plugin::__set_state(array(
   '__initializer__' => 
  Closure::__set_state(array(
  )),
   '__cloner__' => 
  Closure::__set_state(array(
  )),
   '__isInitialized__' => false,
   'pluginId' => 7,
   'pluginName' => '',
   'pagePlugin' => NULL,
   'pluginMappingValue' => '',
   'allowedPlugin' => 0,
   'mainEntity' => 0,
   'autoCompleteIgnorePlugin' => 0,
))
```

When I refresh the object:

```
        $ref = $pagePlugin->getPlugin();
        $test = ORM::getDefaultOrm();
        $test->refresh($ref);
```

The names will be fetched:

```
$ref = {DoctrineProxies\__CG__\Plugin} [11]
 lazyPropertiesDefaults = {array} [0]
 __initializer__ = {Closure} [3]
 __cloner__ = {Closure} [3]
 __isInitialized__ = true
 *Plugin*pluginId = 7
 *Plugin*pluginName = "Header"
 *Plugin*pagePlugin = {Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection} [9]
 *Plugin*pluginMappingValue = "Header"
 *Plugin*allowedPlugin = null
 *Plugin*mainEntity = null
 *Plugin*autoCompleteIgnorePlugin = null
```

Is it possible to specify in the DQL that Doctrine has to fetch the plugin entirely and why does Doctrine fetch that object partial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fetch the `Plugin` too you need to do a so called fetch join. You can read on fetch joining [here in the Doctrine2 documentation chapter **14.2.2. Joins**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins):

> **Fetch Joins:** In addition to the uses of regular joins: Used to fetch related entities and include them in the hydrated result of a query.

In your case you should use query as such to perform a fetch join:

```
$this->orm->createQuery('SELECT pp, p FROM PagePlugin pp JOIN pp.plugin p WHERE pp.page = :page')->setParameter('page', $page)->getResult();
```